# iterating to nth value in python

Tags: python, matlab

How I will iterate for loop in python for 1 to specific value?

I can iterate on list in python like :

```
for x in l:
    print x
```

But.
If i wanted to iterate from 1 to number th, in matlab I will do :

```
str = "abcd"  
for i=1:z
    for j=1:y
        if  s(:,i)==s(j,:)'
            Seq(i)=str(j);
        end
    end
end
```

How I will iterate such in python?

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in range(0, 11):
    print i
```

HTH

Answer (score 1):

Use slice notation (This creates temporary list that contains first n items):

```
>>> s = "abcd"
>>> for x in s[:2]:
...     print(x)
...
a
b
```

or use [`itertools.islice`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> for x in itertools.islice(s, 2):
...     print(x)
...
a
b
```

Answer (score 1):

To access values in lists, use the square brackets for slicing along with the index.

```
for x in l[start:end]:
        print x
```

You have a grate post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1982962) about slice notation

Another grate [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_lists.htm) about lists

Example 1:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for x in myList[:-1]:
    print x
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Example 2:

```
myList = [1, 2, 3, 4]

for x in myList[1:3]:
    print x
```

Output:

```
2
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get use to the idea of `slicing` in `python`, see [Explain Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/pythons-slice-notation)

Non-slicing:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
n = 5

for i in range(n):
  print a[i]
```

With slices:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
n = 5

print a[:n]
```